# Redirect to a different sub-domain from Outlook add-in page

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm currently working on the modification to our Outlook Add-In that requires redirecting a user to a different sub-domain depending on which region the user belongs to. The sub-domain page loads with an office.js exception:

> Function `ContextActivationManager_getAppContextAsync` call failed. ErrorCode is `-2`, exception: `Failed origin check`

Our setup looks like this:

- `https://outlook.company.com` - the domain hosts all urls from the add-in manifest file such as `functionFile`, `composeTaskPane` and `readTaskPaneUrl`
- `https://outlook.subdomain.company.com` - that's the sub-domain user is redirected to from `readTaskPaneUrl` for example. The page also references office.js and allows THE user to perform all regular add-in actions.

Adding subdomain URL to the `AppDomains` section of the manifest file works fine. But we'd like to avoid that to have the flexibility of adding new sub-domains without re-publishing the add-in. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: As you noted AppDomains in the manifest is the only way to do this.

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, but would wildcard support like https://*.company.com in the appdomains described here https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/13314972-support-wildcards-for-appdomains-in-office-add-in help your scenario?

Comment: Yes, a wildcard in the AppDomains section would have solved our problem. We'll go ahead with a reverse proxy for now.

Answer (score 1):

Would it perhaps be feasible for you to create a Web API in the `outlook.company.com` domain to proxy requests to the appropriate `outlook.subdomain.company.com` subdomain(s)? That way, your add-in code would only be accessing resources in the `outlook.company.com` domain, thereby eliminating the need to specify the subdomains in the `AppDomains` section of the manifest.

Comment: Yes, that's the approach we are planning to use unless there is a different way. We'd like to avoid using reverse proxy to decrease the load on our infrastructure and decrease the number of hops for the Outlook add-in http requests.